# C++ assign const to environment variable or default value

Tags: c++, variables, constants, environment, getenv

For an application that uses a number of environment variables, is there some kind of a convention or "best practice" when it comes to grabbing environment variables and putting them into either a struct or a bunch of `const`'s? Obviously, I want to fallback to a default value for each and every environment variable. Right now, using the following seems like a very messy way of doing it:

```
char* x;
const SOME_VARIABLE;
if (NULL == (x = getenv("SOME_VARIABLE")))
    SOME_VARIABLE = 5; // default value
else
    SOME_VARIABLE = x;
```

I could also write a function that wraps `getenv` to return a default value if an environment variable is empty, but I'm not sure if that's even the best way to do it. I could also do away with using `const`, but that doesn't seem like a good thing to do, either.

Any thoughts?

Comment: As an aside, naming any variable or constant in C++ all uppercase is not a good idea as by convention, all uppercase names are used by the preprocessor and a preprocessor macro can easily mangle your variable.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the tip. I was under the impression that constants are generally supposed to be all caps.

Comment: @Dav, you probably learned that style from code where all the constants were macros (`#define SOME_VARIABLE 5`). They're uppercase because they're macros, not because they're constants.

Comment: @dav One convention I've seen is prefixing every constant variable name with "k", as in `kSomeVariable`.

Comment: Ah yes; K for Konstant.  Wait...

Comment: @Rob: Either that, or I picked up the bad habit from Java class. :|

Comment: @dav: In which case you still have learned it the way Rob described, just via a detour through Java. `:)` It is very unfortunate that Java picked several C coding conventions which, for good reason, are considered bad practice in C++.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about:

```
std::string GetEnvironmentVariableOrDefault(const std::string& variable_name, 
                                            const std::string& default_value)
{
    const char* value = getenv(variable_name.c_str());
    return value ? value : default_value;
}
```

Used as:

```
const std::string some_variable = GetEnvironmentVariableOrDefault("SOME_VARIABLE", "5");
```

Comment: Seems like the simplest solution. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest maybe overloading the function name to getenv() as well, it would read more naturally. However the risk is that people will go looking for it in the getenv documentation / header files and might miss that its a local function.

Answer (score 0):

[James McNellis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151292/james-mcnellis) has provided a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936212/c-assign-const-to-environment-variable-or-default-value/3936267#3936267), but here is an alternate opinion:

I think `getenv()` returns the value of the environment variable at the time the program was started. If the environment variable gets changed after the program is started, `getenv()` would still return the old value. Based on that, an alternate approach may be to have a class to capture all the required environment variables as attributes. The class is populated at the start of the program, and provides only (const-qualified) accessor methods. That way the `getenv()` is called **exactly once** for each environment variable. On the negative side, the class takes up some space.

In the alternate approach, which does not use any space, `getenv()` is called whenever the value of any environment variable is required. It’s not that the `getenv()` call is expensive (actually I don’t’ know), but it carries a false assumption to the programmer that the latest value might be returned.

Also having a class may be useful to abstract if there is any dependency in using the environement variables, e.g.

```
if $OS = "SunOs" 
then 
    GCC="/bin/gcc" 
else 
    GCC="/usr/bin/gcc" 

(this is just an example though)
```

Now, a function who don’t care about `$OS` but needs only `$GCC`, can just refer to `envClass->get("GCC");`

Just a thought.

Comment: Good point, although I don't plan on using these constants in *too* many places, so I probably won't have to call `getenv` too many times. A class for this seems a bit overkill IMO, as that's really just duplicating what `getenv` already does.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this with a class that loads configuration settings (either from the environment or a configuration file). I instantiate a single global instance of it at startup.
The program settings are a method or property of the configuration class object.
It's simple and when you write code it's pretty clear what you intended:

```
if ( configuration.ExitOnFailure && IsError() )
   exit();
```